# Angularjs Category Selector

Tags: angularjs

Hello I am building a small web app using meanjs, I have managed to put together a category selector via various tutorials, books etc. it should look like the ebay category selector but I am stuck on how to show the selected categories.

this is what I have so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sibkis/jenvz63e/15/)

```
var app = angular.module('categories', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.choice = null;
$scope.opts = {
    "Basic Materials": {
        "Chemical":{
        "BlahChemicals": ["abc123", "blahblah"],
        "Resources": ["Minerals", "Metals"],
    },
        "Steel":{
        "BlahTin": ["abcsteel", "blahyuck"],
        "Exsteel": ["Minerals", "Metals"],
    },
        "Timber": ["Hardwood", "SoftWood"]
    }

 };
 });

app.directive('catSelect', function($compile, $parse) {
var ddo = {
    restrict: 'E',//only matches element name
    scope: {config:'=config'},
    replace: true,
    controller: function($scope, $attrs, $element) {
        $scope.selected = null; // a place to store the result of this iteration

        // make an selections array to display the current set of keys
        if (angular.isArray($scope.config)) {
            // if it is an array, just copy
            $scope.selections = angular.copy($scope.config);
        } else if (angular.isObject($scope.config)) {
            $scope.selections = [];
            //if it is an object, extract the key's to an array
            angular.forEach($scope.config, function(cat, key) {
                $scope.selections.push(key);
            });
        }

        $scope.$watch("selected", function(newCat, oldCat) {
            if (newCat === oldCat || newCat === null) {return; } //nothing to do.
            $scope.sub = $scope.config[newCat]; //make the current selection the root for the next
            if ($scope.sub && angular.isObject($scope.sub)) { // is there an subselection to make?
                $element.find("span").remove(); //remove previous added selects..
                newSelect = '<cat-select config="sub" class="catSelectSubItem"></cat-select>';
                $element.append($compile(newSelect)($scope));
            }
        });


    },
    template: '<span><select ng-model="selected" ng-options="cat for cat in selections"></span>',

};
return ddo;
});
```

The CSS

```
  select {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 260px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    background: #FFF;
    min-width: 15.0em;
    }
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="categories">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Categories</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8">     </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div>
       <cat-select config="opts"></cat-select>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

So with any luck someone out there will be able to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the multiple selected categories you must keep track of them somehow.

I was able to make a quick edit on your jsFiddle so it stores the selected options in an array and shows that on the HTML... you can then use it on your controller to do whatever you need.

It probably could use some more optimization and defensive coding, but I guess you can do it yourself :)

Here is the fiddle, hope that helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/j8bq7rm1/1/

```
  <div style="display: block;">{{selectedCategories}}</div>
  <div>
      <cat-select config="opts" selected-items="selectedCategories"></cat-select>
  </div>
```

Thanks